# Attributing conversions to the first landing in Google Analytics rather than the most recent referral

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I am new to Google Analytics and I would like to track a first step of our customer. So for example

- Customer1 visited our page on 1st of January 2016 from `google / cpc`.
- Then on 2nd of July 2016 Customer1 completed a conversion from source `facebook / referral`.

GA takes "last step" as a completed goal but in our case is better to know a first step `google / cpc`.

I have just figure out that we can track customers by IPs but I read in GA terms that it is forbidden.

Is there some way how to solve this problem?

Comment: Google Analytics has functionality for this called "attribution modeling".  I've never used it myself, so I can't give you a good answer about how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Analytics, choose **Conversions > Attribution > Model Comparison**.  Here you need to select **First Interaction** to attribute the conversion to the first touchpoint.

You can also compare different attribution models and test more sophisticated models. In the screenshot below. I have selected a comparison of first click and last click attribution models.

[image]